# Конвертировать XML в JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, xml

Добрый день подскажите как реализовать,и если есть возможность покажите как.

Мне приходит xml файл, мне его нужно преобразовать в json(т.к. весь прайс сделан и подключен уже к сайту через json).

Как в итоге это сделать?

Comment: На php например через http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

Answer (score 1):

Ну самый простой метод на `PHP`:

```
<?php
$xml_data = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<plane>
   <year> 1977 </year>
   <make> Cessna </make>
   <model> Skyhawk </model>
   <color> Light blue and white </color>
</plane>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml_data );
$json = json_encode( $xml );

print_r( $json );

?>
```

В итоге должно получиться

`{"year":" 1977 ","make":" Cessna ","model":" Skyhawk ","color":" Light blue and white "}`

Comment: Товаров около 25000 в xml файле

Comment: + еще <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?> кодировка такая

Comment: @Ivan,  25000 - Это не так уж и много )) второе,  <?xml version="1.0" это я как пример показал в $xml_data = должна быть ваш XML данные

Comment: а можно ли через js?

Comment: можете тут посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript